# ORSSerialPort doesn't send data

Tags: macos, orsserialport

I am junior Swift user but on this stage of life I need use serial connection in my project.
when I looking for availeble port ,I see them without problem but when try to send something I have problem why?

I have problem with ORSSerial this my code:

```swift
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification:      Notification) {

        let portEvString = ORSSerialPortManager.shared().availablePorts
        let pathString = portEvString[0].path
        let portClass = SerialController(path:pathString)
        portClass.open()
        portClass.SendString(data: "hello")
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        RunLoop.current.run()
    }

   class SerialController : NSObject, ORSSerialPortDelegate {
        var port : ORSSerialPort?

        init(path: String){
            port = ORSSerialPort(path: path)
            port?.close()
        }

        func open(){
            port?.baudRate=9600
            port?.delegate=self
            port?.open()
        }

        func close(){
            port?.delegate=nil
            port?.close()
        }

        func SendString(data: String){
            let dataa = Data(data.utf8)
            port?.send(dataa)
        }

        func serialPortWasOpened(serialPort: ORSSerialPort!) {
            print("PORT IS OPEN....")
        }

        func serialPortWasClosed(serialPort: ORSSerialPort!) {
            print("PORT IS CLOSE")
        }

        func serialPort(serialPort: ORSSerialPort!, didReceiveData data: NSData!) {
            print(NSString(data: data as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
        }

        func serialPortWasRemovedFromSystem(_ serialPort: ORSSerialPort!) {
            print("PORT REMOVED")
        }

        func serialPort(serialPort: ORSSerialPort!, didEncounterError error: NSError!) {
            print("PORT ERR \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the primary problem is that you don't store the instance of `SerialController` in a strong reference, so it gets deallocated immediately after you call `SendString()` on it. You need to store it in a property like so:

```
var serialController: SerialController?

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification:      Notification) {

    let availablePorts = ORSSerialPortManager.shared().availablePorts
    let pathString = availablePorts[0].path
    serialController = SerialController(path:pathString)
    serialController?.open()
    serialController?.SendString(data: "hello")
}
```

Beyond that problem, there are a number of things about this code that you should fix. The things that stick out most:

- Don't call `RunLoop.current.run()` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)`. You rarely need to manually run the run loop, and you definitely don't need to here.
- As [documented](https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort/blob/597fff1d266b0045c6d8760e05e7c419489f7b7f/Source/ORSSerialPort.h#L582) in ORSSerialPort, you *must* release any strong references to the port in your implementation of `serialPortWasRemovedFromSystem(_:)`. That means in that method, you need to do `port = nil`.
- The force unwrap operators (`!`) scattered through this code make me wonder if you're using an old version of ORSSerialPort, from before I added nullability annotations. Please make sure you're using the latest version (2.0.2 as of this writing).
- Use more descriptive names for your variables. For example, `portEvString` is not a good name, because it's difficult to understand (what does "Ev" mean?), and its type is *not* a string, it's an array of `ORSSerialPort` objects (ie. `[ORSSerialPort]`.
- Your `SendString` method shouldn't start with a capital letter. Function (and method) names in Swift should always start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

After the disable SandBox, everything is OK.